# Scraping Kickstarter With R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, scrapy

I tried to scrape Kickstarter. However I do not get a result when I try to get the URLs that refer to the projects.

This should be one of the results:

https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1534822242/david-bowie-hunger-city-photo-story?ref=category_ending_soon

and this is my code:

Code:

```
    main.page1 <- read_html(x ="https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?
    category_id=1&sort=end_date&seed=2498921&page=1")

    urls1 <- main.page1 %>% # feed `main.page` to the next step
            html_nodes(".block.img-placeholder.w100p") %>% # get the CSS nodes
            html_attr("href") # extract the URLs
```

Does anyone see where I go wrong?

Comment: It looks like the page uses Ajax to fill in the details - the .img-placeholder divs are empty (and also don't seem to have the .block class) when loaded. See `html_nodes(main.page1,"div.img-placeholder")`

Comment: @Spacedman Do you know how I can get these scripts into a dataframe in R?

Comment: Actually it looks like the placeholders are filled from "data-project" attributes from another div.... hang on..,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First declare all the packages you use - I had to go search to realise I needed `rvest`:

```
> library(rvest)
> library(dplyr)
```

Get your HTML:

```
> main.page1 <- read_html(x ="https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?category_id=1&sort=end_date&seed=2498921&page=1")
```

As that stands, the data for each project is stashed in a `data-project` attribute in a bunch of divs. Some Javascript (I suspect built using the React framework) in the browser will normally fill the other DIVs in and get the images, format the links etc. But you have just grabbed the raw HTML so that isn't available. But the raw data is.... So....

The relevant divs appear to be class "react-disc-landing" so this gets the data as text strings:

```
> data = main.page1 %>% 
    html_nodes("div.react-disc-landing") %>% 
    html_attr("data-project")
```

These things appear to be JSON strings:

```
> substr(data[[1]],1,80)
[1] "{\"id\":208460273,\"photo\":{\"key\":\"assets/017/007/465/9b725fdf5ba1ee63e8987e26a1d33"
```

So let's use the `rjson` package to decode the first one:

```
> library(rjson)
> jdata = fromJSON(data[[1]])
```

`jdata` is now a very complex nested list. Use `str(jdata)` to see what is in it. I'm not sure what bit of it you want, but maybe this URL:

```
> jdata$urls$web$project
[1] "https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1513052868/sense-of-place-by-jose-davila"
```

If not, the URL you want must be in that structure somewhere.

Repeat over `data[[i]]` to get all links.

### Note that you should check the site T+Cs that you are allowed to do this, and also see if there's an API you should really be using.

Comment: Just a heads up the `read_html` line throws this error for me: `Error in open.connection(x, "rb"): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates`

Comment: @Mako212 its just the same line as in the question, so it works for me and I presume the questioner. Must be your local installation/network setup.

Comment: Great solution! Now I have one problem left though.. I would like to get all the 26,449 links, but it seems that I can only get 13. Even when I change the &page=1 to other numbers it will give me the first 13 links. It is the same for you @Spacedman? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: This is clearly beyond the T+Cs: "Don’t use any kind of software or device (whether it’s manual or automated) to “crawl” or “spider” any part of the Site."